# Aurelia - Issues with two "Fetches" where the second finishes and loads localStorage after new page is rendered

Tags: javascript, fetch, aurelia

I have a fetch that goes off and gets JWT token and then saves it to local storage. This works.

I have then chained ".then" to the initial fetch and via a function called another fetch to go and get the username and password from the API and then saved that to local storage.

The final ".then" resets the root to a new root. (that works)... and the first localStorage saving of the JWT and loggedIn also is done before the setRoot call starts, however....

My problem is that I am finding the save of the username to localStorage from the second Fetch happens after the new root page has run its constructor where it trys to get the username  from localStorage.  The 'username' in localStorage had not been set yet as the second fetch has not finished yet...

How do I make sure all my fetches and all saves to localStorage have been successfully saved before I reset the root?

Here is my login.ts file where I do the initial fetch.

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    this.userLogin.Username = username;
    this.userLogin.Password = password;

    // Lets do a fetch!
    const task = fetch("/api/jwt", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.userLogin),
        headers: new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log("data - in FETCH: ", data);
            localStorage.setItem(this.TOKEN_KEY, JSON.stringify(data));
            localStorage.setItem(this.LOGGED_IN, JSON.stringify("authenticated"));

        })
        .then(() => {
            this.saveUserDetail();
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log(" before redirect USERNAME_KEY): ", localStorage.getItem(this.USERNAME_KEY));
            this.router.navigate('/', { replace: true, trigger: false });
            this.router.reset();
            this.aurelia.setRoot('app/app/app');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.clearIdentity();
        });
```

you can see that I call this.saveUserDetail() in the third ".then" and in the fouth ".then" I do a aurelia.setRoot('...').

Here is my this.saveUserDetail() function with the second fetch.

```
saveUserDetail() {
    const session = this.getIdentity();
    if (!session) {
        throw new Error("No JWT present");
    }
    const token = session.access_token;

    const headers = new Headers({
        Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });

    const task = fetch("/api/jwt/userDetail", {
        method: "GET",
        headers
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            try {
                console.log("data.stringify: ", JSON.stringify(data));
                localStorage.setItem(this.USERNAME_KEY, data.username);
                localStorage.setItem(this.USERROLES_KEY, data.role);
            } catch (Error) { }

            console.log("localStorage.getItem(this.USERNAME_KEY): ", localStorage.getItem(this.USERNAME_KEY));
        });
}
```

I was under the impression I should go back to the API for the username.  Maybe I can do it in one fetch etc is there a way I can have localStorage loaded with everything BEFORE I do an "aurelia.setroot()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `return` so the promise returned by `this.saveUserDetail()` is waited for - oh, wait, you need to return a promise in `saveUserDetail` too

so

```
.then(() => {
    return this.saveUserDetail();
})
```

or

```
.then(this.saveUserDetail) // note, pass the function, don't call it
```

and changes to saveUserDetail

```
saveUserDetail() {
    // all your code, then at the bottom of the function add:
    return task;
}
```

Comment: That works. Had a go at the same method but I was not aware of "return task" after the finish of the fetch. Finally I have the username showing up in the new root. Thankyou.